# Equations for Mandelbrot bifurcation diagram

Tags: dynamical-systems, closed-form, fractals, chaos-theory, bifurcation

The Mandelbrot set is the set of all complex numbers $c$ that cause the function $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$ to remain bounded within a circle of radius 2 when iterated from $z_0 = 0$. Looking at only the real numbers, all values between positive $\frac{1}{4}$ and negative 2 are part of the set. If we plot the attractive fixed point value on the vertical axis against the input $c$ value on the horizontal axis we get a classic bifurcation diagram. Going from right to left, the diagram starts with the function $\frac{1 - \sqrt{-4c + 1}}{2}$ where $\frac{1}{4} ≥ c ≥ -\frac{3}{4}$. It then splits into two branches as $\frac{-1 ± \sqrt{-4c + 3}}{2}$ where $-\frac{3}{4} ≥ c ≥ -\frac{5}{4}$. Both branches divide again and again, over increasingly narrow intervals, until the plot dissolves into chaos around $-\frac{7}{5}$.

[image: Bifurcation diagram of the Mandelbrot set.]

**Are there closed-form equations for any of the divisions beyond the first two I've listed?** For example, the period-4 region or the period-8 region? They don't seem to line up with quadratic expressions or any other expressions I've tried. I also can't find closed-form expressions for the end-points of the intervals for each division, that is, the $c$ value for each bifurcation point.

The closest I've been able to get so far for the topmost period-four section is $\frac{(-4c - 5)^{\frac{1}{2.05}}} {2.5} - \frac{1 - \sqrt{2}} {2}$, which is pretty darn close, but it's not exact.

I do know that the sweeping curves visible in the chaotic portion of the bifurcation diagram, the critical curves, are of the form $(c² + c)² + c$, $((c² + c)² + c)² + c$, $(((c² + c)² + c)² + c)² + c$, and so on, but these curves don't line up with the bifurcating parts either.

Comment: How "closed form" do you need? Those curves are solutions to polynomials... but the degree of those polynomials is, uh, enormous (and not ones with a nice expressions by radicals)

Comment: @MiloBrandt I'll take complicated answers. How enormous are you talking?

Comment: See also Feigenbaum diagram and Feigenbaum numbers for the general dynamic of the bifurcations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let
$$f_c(z)=z^2+c$$
then the lines on that diagram (in the column corresponding to $c$) are exactly at attractive cycles of $f_c$ - which is to say that they are certain solutions of
$$f_c^n(z)=z$$
where $f_c^n$ is the $n$-fold composition of $f_c$ with itself - and where $n$ will be the number of lines seen on the plot. More specifically, they are the solutions for which the derivative $|(f_c^n)'(z)| \leq 1$.

So, the curves are described as some of the roots of the following degree $2^n$ polynomial in $z$ (but note that cycles of every length appear in that plot - so certain pieces will require arbitrarily large $n$ to describe):
$$f_c^n(z)-z.$$
You can *slightly* reduce this by noting that if $m$ divides $n$ then $f_c^m(z)-z$ divides $f_c^n(z)-z$, which at least lets us factor the polynomial a little bit. As far as I know, the only $n$ for which the solutions of this have a form with radicals is $n=1$ (the fixed point) and $n=2$ (the two-cycle).

You can certainly, however, solve these equations using numerical methods for solving polynomials - and even something simple such as Newton's method is going to converge a lot faster than finding the cycles just by iterating a single point (as is how bifurcations diagrams are usually made) under $f_c$ itself.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, you're saying that the curves in the period-4 region are solutions to the expression $f(f(f(f(z)))) = z$?

Comment: @Lawton : Or slightly simplified $(f(f(f(f(z))))-z)/(f(f(z))-z)$. The quotient still has degree $16-4=12$, the roots forming 3 4-cycles, of which one is real and stable in the period-4 region.

Comment: How do I go from that to something I can plug into a graphing calculator?

Comment: @Lawton I don't really have any good suggestions for that - it depends a lot on what exactly your calculator can do (or what you can do with a calculator); inherently, this is just an implicit equation (i.e. it says "$z$ and $c$ must satisfy this" rather than giving either a function of the other) - some tools can do that easily. However, this is also the exact kind of problem that leads people to use more sophisticated means of computation (e.g. using various math software systems or programming languages) - and I don't have good advice on dealing with those things.